# How to mock a private dao variable?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a `dao.create()` call that I want to mock when testing a method.
But I am missing something as I'm still getting NPE. What is wrong here?

```
class MyService {
    @Inject
    private Dao dao;

    public void myMethod() {
        //..
        dao.create(object);
        //
    }
}
```

How can I mock out the dao.create() call?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(DAO.class)
public void MyServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void testMyMethod() {
        PowerMockito.mock(DAO.class);

        MyService service = new MyService();
        service.myMethod(); //NPE for dao.create()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the class "DAO" or "Dao"?

Comment: Some good solutions depend on the dependency injection framework you're using. Please add an appropriate tag (guice, spring, ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not injecting the DAO. With mockito you can change your test class to use @InjectMocks and use mockito runner.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public void MyServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private Dao dao;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;
    ...
}
```

You can read more about InjectMocks at [Inject Mocks API](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html)

Simpler way is changing your injection to injection by constructor. For example, you would change MyService to

```
class MyService {
    ...
    private final Dao dao;

    @Inject
    public MyService(Dao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    } 
    ...
}
```

then your test you could simple pass the mocked DAO in setup.

```
...
@Mock
private Dao dao;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.dao = mock(Dao.class);
    this.service = new MyService(dao);
}
...
```

now you can use `verify` to check if `create` was called, like:

```
...
   verify(dao).create(argThat(isExpectedObjectBeingCreated(object)));
}

private Matcher<?> isExpectedObjectBeingCreated(Object object) { ... }
```

Using injection by constructor will let your dependencies clearer to other developers and it will help when creating tests :)

Comment: Sorry about the poor english :P

Answer (score 1):

You still need to set the dao field with your mock.
You can use reflection to this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject/set the mocked object DAO in your service class.

If it is a spring based project, you may have a look @ Spring Junit Testrunner

Answer (score 0):

If you use `new MyService()` the Dao is never injected. For the Dao to be injected you need to load the MyService via an `ApplicationContext` (Spring) or an `Injector` (Guice). Like you would in your normal application.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, you need to set the `dao` field in your `MyService` class in some fashion.  I'm unsure the mechanism to allow for a compound runner on your test to use both Powermock and a DI framework runner (assuming Powermock is required), but as long as you're already using PowerMock (for reasons unclear in the given example), you could avail yourself of the [Whitebox](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.3.7/apidocs/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html) class to set the dao more manually.

```
public void testMyMethod() {
    Dao dao = mock(Dao.class)
    doNothing().when(dao).create(anyObject())); //assuming no return val for dao.create()

    MyService service = new MyService();
    Whitebox.setInternalState(service, "dao", dao);

    service.myMethod(); 
}
```