# Mockito: Mock private field initialization

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermockito

How I can mock a field variable which is being initialized inline?

```
class Test {
    private Person person = new Person();
    ...
    public void testMethod() {
        person.someMethod();
        ...
    }
}
```

Here I want to mock `person.someMethod()` while testing the `Test.testMethod()` method for which I need to mock initialization of `person` variable. Any clue?

**Edit:** I'm not allowed to modify Person class.

Comment: This link might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645571/how-to-mock-a-private-dao-variable

Comment: You should refactor your code so that you can pass in a mock for `Person`.  Options include adding a constructor to do this, or adding a setter method.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I already found the solution to this problem which I forgot to post here.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ Test.class })
public class SampleTest {

@Mock
Person person;

@Test
public void testPrintName() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Person.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(person);
    Test test= new Test();
    test.testMethod();
    }
}
```

Key points to this solution are:

1. Running my test cases with PowerMockRunner: `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`
2. Instruct Powermock to prepare `Test.class` for manipulation of private fields: `@PrepareForTest({ Test.class })`
3. And finally mock the constructor for Person class:

   `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Person.class);`
   `PowerMockito.whenNew(Person.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(person);`

Comment: Your explanation talks about the `mockStatic` function, but that is not represented in your code example. Should the code example have the `mockStatic` call, or is that not required for constructors?

Answer (score 150):

Mockito comes with a helper class to save you some reflection boiler plate code:

```
import org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.Whitebox;

//...

@Mock
private Person mockedPerson;
private Test underTest;

// ...

@Test
public void testMethod() {
    Whitebox.setInternalState(underTest, "person", mockedPerson);
    // ...
}
```

**Update:**
Unfortunately the mockito team decided to [remove the class](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/489) in Mockito 2. So you are back to writing your own reflection boilerplate code, use another library (e.g. [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/package-summary.html)), or simply pilfer the [Whitebox](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/fea4074f8d4a7b1f7b8e89d4819bef25b1b6228f/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/util/reflection/Whitebox.java) class (it is [MIT licensed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)).

**Update 2:**
JUnit 5 comes with its own [ReflectionSupport](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.commons/org/junit/platform/commons/support/ReflectionSupport.html) and [AnnotationSupport](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.commons/org/junit/platform/commons/support/AnnotationSupport.html) classes that might be useful and save you from pulling in yet another library.

Comment: I'm spying my target object because of other reasons and in this case when my object is spy, I cannot set internal state this way.

Comment: Why not? I am using it with spies. Create a Person instance. Stub whatever needs stubbing, then set it on your Test instance.

Comment: Warning: Whitebox is in the `internal` package and does not seem to work anymore on Mockito 2.6.2.

Comment: You can use FieldSetter.setField(). I've given an example below for the same.

Comment: This seems brittle because there is no compiler check that you are using the correct field name, and it could break when the code changes without notification.  Using the `@PowerMockRunner` class annotation as described in another answer seems like the way to go.

Comment: @JoeCoder, depending on the code change the PowerMock solution is very likely to break just the same without the compiler catching it. E.g. if you add another `Person` field to the class under test or remove the person member. I don't see the harm though. As long as the test verifies expected behavior properly it will go red after the code change and thus fulfills its purpose.

Comment: @Ralf PowerMock's injection of `Person::new` occurs for all instances of `Person`, so it would still work.  The one drawback I've found is that some test runners (such as SonarQube's code coverage tool) do not work with `@PowerMockRunner`.

Comment: @JoeCoder, the behavior to be verified for the second `Person` is likely to be different from the first person...

Comment: @Ralf Not a problem. `Person::new` is only injected in the class referenced in the `@PrepareForTest` annotation, e.g `@PrepareForTest({PersonFactory.class})`.  You could create regular mock `Person` instances and pass them into the injector as needed in the test code, e.g. `PowerMockito.whenNew(Person.class).withArguments("Frank").thenReturn(frank);`

Comment: @JoeCoder, of course you can do that. Just like you can adapt the plain vanilla Mockito test. But in both cases the compiler won't tell you that you have to do it. Which was your criticism of the solution using just Mockito and some reflection support.

Comment: @Ralk My criticism is this: if the private instance member `Test::person` is changed to `Test::human`, this is an implementation detail and the unit test should not fail on that, but it does when reflection is used, and it fails silently.

Comment: @JoeCoder, I don't see why it should fail silently? The test will go red, most likely because the reflection code will through an exception or at the latest because the code under test throws an NPE.

Comment: @Ralf Because changing a reference name in Java should always result in a compilation error.

Answer (score 119):

In case you use Spring Test try *org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils*

```
 ReflectionTestUtils.setField(testObject, "person", mockedPerson);
```

Comment: Great! Might help to link to this article and maybe include the dependencies one needs from it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reflection-test-utils

Comment: build.gradle.kts: `testImplementation("org.springframework:spring-test:5.1.2.RELEASE")`

Comment: This is not useful for JUnit 5 or spring: 2.4.2 version

Comment: @SolankiVaibhav why not?

Answer (score 98):

Pretty late to the party, but I was struck here and got help from a friend. The thing was not to use PowerMock. This works with the latest version of Mockito.

Mockito comes with this `org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldSetter`.

What it basically does is helps you modify private fields using reflection.

This is how you use it:

```
@Mock
private Person mockedPerson;
private Test underTest;

// ...

@Test
public void testMethod() {
    FieldSetter.setField(underTest, underTest.getClass().getDeclaredField("person"), mockedPerson);
    // ...
    verify(mockedPerson).someMethod();
}
```

This way you can pass a mock object and then verify it later.

[Here](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldSetter/set) is the reference.

Comment: `FieldSetter` is not available anymore in Mockito 2.x.

Comment: @Ralf I'm using version mockito-core-2.15.0. It's available there. https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.0.15-beta/org/mockito/internal/util/reflection/FieldSetter.html.
Still beta though.

Comment: @RajKumar the `Class#getDeclaredField` accepts single param, so the parens need to look like this`FieldSetter.setField(underTest, underTest.getClass().getDeclaredField("person"), mockedPerson);`. That was how I got it wrong and thought might be a good idea to fix it in your example. Thanks for replying.

Comment: using internal API is not the best idea

Comment: @RajKumar Nice, but as Zimbo Rodger mentioned: Is it a good idea to use an internal API? Why is it internal acutally? It is so useful for testing.

Comment: I don't understand, how could this work with private field? underTest.getClass().getDeclaredField("person") will throw NoSuchFieldException I think.

Answer (score 12):

Following code can be used to initialize mapper in REST client mock. The `mapper` field is private and needs to be set during unit test setup.

```
import org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldSetter;

new FieldSetter(client, Client.class.getDeclaredField("mapper")).set(new Mapper());
```

Answer (score 11):

if u are using spring boot test and cant find neither of `WhiteBox`, `FeildSetter`; u can simply use `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils`

this is an example:

```java
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

//...

@Mock
private Person mockedPerson;
private Test underTest;

// ...

@Test
public void testMethod() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(underTestObject, "person", mockedPerson);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The best way until now, I think that is

`org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils`

Im about to mock the `private String mockField` in FooService.class inside FooServiceTest.java

FooService.java:

```
  @Value("${url.image.latest}")
  private String latestImageUrl;
```

FooServiceTest.java:

```
  @InjectMocks
  FooService service;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, // inject into this object
        "latestImageUrl", // assign to this field
        "your value here"); // object to be injected
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Using @Jarda's guide you can define this if you need to set the variable the same value for all tests:

```
@Before
public void setClientMapper() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException{
    FieldSetter.setField(client, client.getClass().getDeclaredField("mapper"), new Mapper());
}
```

But beware that setting private values to be different should be handled with care. If they are private are for some reason.

Example, I use it, for example, to change the wait time of a sleep in the unit tests. In real examples I want to sleep for 10 seconds but in unit-test I'm satisfied if it's immediate. In integration tests you should test the real value.

Answer (score 4):

commons-lang3

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;

FieldUtils.writeField(object, fieldName, value, true);
```

Comment: (from review) could you add a little more about how this works?