# Google Mock: Mock private variable member that is instantiated in target class's constructor

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, googletest, googlemock

My question is the same as [Mockito: Mock private field initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173947/mockito-mock-private-field-initialization) but for Google Mock framework. In a nutshell:

```
class Target {
private:
    Person person = new Person();

public:
    void testMethod() {
        person.someMethod();
    }
};
```

How can I mock the `person` instance while making unit tests for `Target` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-answer here: simply don't do it this way.

Your problem is the call to `new` here. Thing is: that makes testing hard, and it also creates a very tight coupling between the `Target` and the `Person` class.

The default alternative is: provide a *factory* to the `Target` class that creates `Person` objects for you.

By going for that solution, you

- avoid to need to mock the call to `new`
- you end up with a better design!

And unless I am misreading the [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/ForDummies.md), mocking calls to `new` isn't possible with C++ mocking anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you are gonna say. But I am working on adding unit tests for an in-production project and I am ending up using a lot of preprocessor directives to workaround this kind of issues :(

Comment: Could you please give me some advice with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994780/unit-testing-am-i-doing-right-when-using-another-method-in-unit-testing-a-metho)