# Mocking a Class For Unit Tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I've `Class A` that has an instance of another `Class B`. I've completed unit testing of independent code in `Class B`. For other operations, `Class A` invokes methods of `Class B`, does some processing using other classes and then invokes methods of `Class B`.

My question is how do I mock the dependency of `Class A` and complete unit testing of `Class B`? If `Class B` uses instance of `Class A`, I can mock `Class A` and complete the task. However, in my case `Class A` uses instance of `Class B`.

How do I mock in this scenario for unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you have designed your `class A` and `class B`.

If they have been well-designed then you can easily make mock implementation for `interface IB` - interface of B - (using GoogleTest & GoogleMock) then use this mock implementation in unit tests of `class A`. To see how to use GoogleMock, check [GoogleMock CheatSheet](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md).

Otherwise, you may have run into a situation similar to [Google Mock: Mock private variable member that is instantiated in target class's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916123/google-mock-mock-private-variable-member-that-is-instantiated-in-target-classs) then you may need to use some `preprocessor directives` to break your `class A`.