# Mock a new Object created at class level

Tags: java, mockito

I have a SenderService class as shown below.

I am using the restTemplate object to call a url. How should I write a junit test for this by ONLY using Mockito ?

I have already tried creating a spy for my class but its not working

```
@Service
public class SenderServiceImpl implements SenderService{

    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

     @Override
    public void sendNotification(SenderNotification notification) {
        try {
            HttpEntity sendRequestBody = new HttpEntity<> 
            (notification,headers);
            response = 
            restTemplate.postForEntity(url,sendRequestBody,String.class); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Pass in a `RestTemplate` instance to the constructor of `SenderServiceImpl` so that you can mock it, instead of creating it inside the class

Comment: PS : I cannot make changes in the code as its not owned by me

Comment: Then why are you testing it? You won't be able to fix any bug you might find anyway. You can use the Mock and InjectMocks annotations (https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#21), but something is seriously wrong if you're supposed to unit test code that you're not allowed to modify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito: Mock private field initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173947/mockito-mock-private-field-initialization)

Comment: You can possibly use powermock (https://automationrhapsody.com/mock-new-object-creation-powermock/). But this is not clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments-this code needs dependency injection and should rather be fixed.
If you really want to mock field you can use PowerMock
or the solution from this question:
[Mockito: Mock private field initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173947/mockito-mock-private-field-initialization)

> Mockito comes with a helper class to save you some reflection boiler
>   plate code:
>
> ```
> import org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.Whitebox;
>
> //...
>
> @Mock
> private Person mockedPerson;
> private Test underTest;
>
> // ...
>
> @Test
> public void testMethod() {
>     Whitebox.setInternalState(underTest, "person", mockedPerson);
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Comment: What fix would you suggest, if not injecting the instance?

Comment: omg silly me, it supposed to be "this code needs dependency injection"