# Mock private wrapper/primitive/String field

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

My question is not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173947/mockito-mock-private-field-initialization) question.
I want to mock private **wrapper** fields like Integer and String.
Also, these fields are in an abstract super class.

```
public abstract class SuperSample
{
    private Integer var1;
    private String var2;

    private Service service;

    pubic boolean foo()
    {
          int a = service.doStuff(var1, var2);
          return subMethod(a);
    }

    protected abstract boolean subMethod(int var);

    public void setVar1(Integer var1)
    {
        this.va1 = var1;
    }

    public Integer getVar1()
    {
        return var1;
    }

    public void setVar2(String var2)
    {
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    public String getVar2()
    {
        return var2;
    }

    public void setService(Service service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public String getService()
    {
        return service;
    }
}

public class Sample extends SuperSample
{
    protected boolean subMethod(int var)
    {
        return var%2==0?true:false;
    }
}
```

Spring.xml -

```
<bean id="superSample" class="SuperSample" abstract="true">
    <property name="var1" value="2" />
    <property name="var2" value="cool" />
</bean>

<bean id="sample" class="Sample" >
    <property name="service" ref="service" />
</bean>
```

In my junit I can't mock or spy var1 or var2. On spying/mocking var1, var2 I get the error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  Cannot mock/spy class
>   java.lang.Integer Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
>     - final classes
>     - anonymous classes
>     - primitive types

I want to mock the line -

```
service.doStuff(var1, var2)
```

with something like-

```
@UnitTest
public class SampleTest
{
    @Mock 
    private Service service;

    private Integer var1 = 2
    private String var2 = "cool";

    @InjectMocks
    private Sample sample;  

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 
        Mockito.when(service.doStuff(var1, var2)).thenReturn(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider using [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockfinal) to mock final classes?

Comment: This appears to be an XY question. Why **do** you need to mock `Integer`? What benefit would making `Integer.valueOf(1).intValue()` return a `2` give to your tests? Why can't you solve it the other way?

Comment: Do you want to mock `service.doStuff(var1, var2);` or what exactly?

Comment: If you want to mock `service.doStuff`, you need to, well, mock the `Service` and give your `Sample` instance the mock of the `Service` instead of the actual `Service`.

Comment: Where is `service` assigned in the shown example?

Comment: @Nkosi: Service is populated from spring.xml

Comment: @FarrukhChishti Convert to using constructor injection, and then it's trivial to pass a mock to the constructor.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- : Can't do that. The fields `var1` and `var2` are getting populated from spring.xml

Comment: @FarrukhChishti Spring has supported constructor injection for at least the past 12 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply inject the values yourself and then remove the `@InjectMocks` annotation. This can best be done in a setup method annotated with `@Before` so it gets executed for every test.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    sample = new Sample();
    sample.setVar1(1234);
    sample.setVar2("5678");
    sample.setService(service);
}
```

Comment: on applying debug on the method `foo()`

Comment: @FarrukhChishti have you used my `setup()` method?  and is it annotated with `@Before` (or the equivalent in other testing frameworks) so that it runs before every test?

Comment: yes...i have also updated my question....these variables are actually in an abstract super class....can you please have a look again...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on currently shown example the mock can be injected via the set member

```
@UnitTest
public class SampleTest {
    @Mock 
    private Service service;

    private Integer var1 = 2
    private String var2 = "cool";

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //Arrange
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        Sample sample = new Sample();
        sample.setService(service);
        sample.setVar1(var1);
        sample.setVar2(var2);          

        Mockito.when(service.doStuff(var1, var2)).thenReturn(5);

        //Act
        boolean actual = sample.foo();

        //Assert

        //...
    }
}
```

Ideally, the more SOLID design approach would be to refactor the subject class to use explicit dependency principle via constructor injection

```
public class Sample extends SuperSample {

    public Sample(Service service) {
        super.setService(service);
    }

    protected boolean subMethod(int var) {
        return var%2==0?true:false;
    }
}
```

Allowing any explicit dependencies to be injected

```
@UnitTest
public class SampleTest {
    @Mock 
    private Service service;

    private Integer var1 = 2
    private String var2 = "cool";

    @InjectMocks
    private Sample sample;  

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //Arrange
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); 

        sample.setVar1(var1);
        sample.setVar2(var2);  

        Mockito.when(service.doStuff(var1, var2)).thenReturn(5);

        //Act
        boolean actual = sample.foo();

        //Assert

        //... 
    }
}
```

Comment: but I am injecting the bean and the variables from spring.xml. Why override the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, we created a JUnit extension to solve this precise problem.

https://github.com/exabrial/mockito-object-injection

Comment: Thanks a ton !!!!
Honestly, this was amazing. Please feel free to ask for my kidney any day of the year.