# In Java unit testing, how to verify a variable of type Function is called with certain arguments passed in?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a variable of type `Function` like:

```
Class SomeClass{ 
    static final Function<Throwable, Optional<String>> SOME_FUNCTION = throwable -> Optional.empty();
}
```

I am wondering how to verify it was called for certain times and was passed in certain arguments?

What I need is the equivalent of the following code:

`verify(SomeClass, times(2)).SOME_FUNCTION(any(Exception.class));`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you mean `verify(ITS_CLASS, times(2)).apply(any(Exception.class));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `SOME_FUNCTION` with a Mockito mock that you can assert invocations on. Depending on your situation, there might be several ways to achieve this:

#### Pass in the function as a member

If the function you need to perform assertions on does not necessarily need to be final static, and it makes sense in your situation to pass it in:

```java
class MyClass {
    final Function<Throwable, Optional<String>> someFunction;

    public MyClass(Function<Throwable, Optional<String>> someFunction) {
        this.someFunction = someFunction;
    }

    // ...
}
```

then you can pass in a mock in your test:

```java
Function<Throwable, Optional<String>> mockFunc = Mockito.mock(Function.class);
var myClass = new MyClass(mockFunc);
// ... test code ...
verify(mockFunc, times(2)).apply(any(Exception.class));
```

If the function needs to stay static but you still can make the variable non-final, then you can just change it by static assignment and it should work the same. Just remember to set it back to its original value afterwards in this case.

#### Mock the static member using reflection

If you cannot alter the class' code, and *need* to perform assertions on the static function, it becomes a bit more tricky. You can attempt to replace the function with a mock using reflection. Mockito has a `Whitebox` class which encapsules some of that:

```java
Function<Throwable, Optional<String>> mockFunc = Mockito.mock(Function.class);
Whitebox.setInternalState(MyClass.class, "SOME_FUNCTION", mockFunc);
// ... test code ...
verify(mockFunc, times(2)).apply(any(Exception.class));
```

But this most probably has some unwanted side effects (like `SOME_FUNCTION` staying a mock longer than intended) and should only be a last resort.

Comment: I used the Whitebox approach but `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to set internal state on a private field. Please report to mockito mailing list.` occurred. Could you please help me with it? I already made the `SOME_FUNCTION` public (just for trial)..

Comment: Hmm... Whitebox might work differently than I remember or you are using a version of Mockito I am not familiar with. You may try using `FieldSetter` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51499019/3688648 or if that fails too, you could write some reflection code by hand.

Comment: I think `SOME_FUNCTION` cannot be `final`. After I deleted `final` it is OK. Thank you anyway!