# [Mockito]NullPointerException due to private method called

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I have an object that contain a private method(**mylog**), when I want to mock a method(**myMethod**) that call the private method it throw me an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here my code :

```scala
object myObject {

  private val mylog = new Logger("Title")

  def myMethod(parameter1: Int): Int = {
    mylog.info("I log a message here")
    parameter1
  }
}
```

Here my mock method

```scala
withObjectMocked[myObject.type] {
          when(myObject.myMethod(ArgumentMatchers.any()).thenCallRealMethod()
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Well, of course ... `mylog` is null. Make it public and mock it. Or use `spy` instead of `mock` (not usually recommended). You could also use `PowerMock` as described in the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173947/mockito-mock-private-field-initialization), but personally I think, that is even uglier than `spy`. But at a higher level, calling real methods in mocked objects is "code smell". It suggests that your code can benefit from some refactoring to make it more unit-test-friendly.

Comment: thank your answer. I'll try it

Comment: are you using Mockito-core or Mockito-scala? I am guessing Mockito-scala because you use withObjectMocked